# What does it mean to "place" a type in a class?

Tags: java, generics

I am reading oracles tutorial on Generic Types and the first paragraph is really messing with my head. The page is here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html The tutorial starts out with a class named "Box":

```
public class Box {
private Object object;

public void set(Object object) { this.object = object; }
public Object get() { return object; }
}
```

and the paragraph that follows is also the one I cannot for the life of me make any sense out of, it reads:

> Since its methods accept or return an Object, you are free to pass in whatever you want, provided that it is not one of the primitive types. There is no way to verify, at compile time, how the class is used. One part of the code may place an Integer in the box and expect to get Integers out of it, while another part of the code may mistakenly pass in a String, resulting in a runtime error.

The last sentence makes absolutely no sense to me, and I've read the rest of that specific page and still can't make out exactly what they are trying to say and feel like I'm missing a big part of the lesson. What does it mean to "place" something in box?

I've tried everything, I tried instantiating the Box class a thousand different ways for this to make sense, they all result in compile time error not run-time. I cannot make sense of this no matter what angle I look at it, am having incredible difficult time deciphering what this means

Comment: Each instance of `Box` has a field `Object object`. "Placing" something in a `Box` means "setting this field to a value" (by calling the `set(...)` method with some argument).

Comment: First it says you can pass anything into the set method as long as it's not a primitive type, which is obviously true, so I can pass a reference of type String to the method, and the method will set that field value to a String, resulting in no run time error. That's what I don't get, it seems like first they are saying I can pass anything, and then they're are saying I can't

Comment: *What does it mean to “place” a type in a class?* I have no idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since we are in the context of a `Box` class - a class that is an abstraction of a physical box - "placing" an integer into the box is just an abstract way of saying "setting the `object` field to an instance of `Integer`".

As for your comment:

> it seems like first they are saying I can pass anything, and then they're are saying I can't

This is what the last sentence meant: You might have code like this:

```
Box b = new Box();
b.set(1); // I've put an integer into the box, I should be able to get integers out of it later on

...

Integer i = (Integer)b.get();
```

The "another part of code" that the tutorial is referring to, is the "..." part. If "..." actually has a line like this:

```
b.set("String"); // I forgot that I'm supposed to only put Integers in the box
```

Then the last line would throw an exception.

Generics solves this problem by making something like `b.setObject("String");` issue a compiler error.

Comment: This is the right answer.  The use of “place in a box” is simply extending the metaphor of a physical real world box, which is what the Box class represents.

Answer (score 0):

Each instance of `Box` has a field `Object object`. "Placing" something in a `Box` means "setting this field to a value" (by calling the `set(...)` method with some argument).

For example, let us imagine we have a `Box box = new Box();`. If we call `box.set("Hello")`, then `box`'s `object` will be set to the `String "Hello"`. In consequence, we could `String s = (String) box.get();`, and `s` will reference the `String "Hello"`. We have to cast the result since `get()` returns an `Object`.

Now imagine that someone calls `box.set(new Integer(10));`. `Integer` is not a `String`, and `String` is not a superclass of `Integer` either. Thus, when we now call `String s = (String) box.get()`, the cast to `String` will fail **at runtime** with a `ClassCastException`.

This mistake could be detected **at compile time**, if we had a possibility to somehow declare that the box we want to use will hold an `Integer` or `String`, or whatever it is we want to store in it. That is where generics come into the picture. We can write something like

```
public class Box<T> {
    private T t;

    public void set(T t) { this.t = t; }
    public T get() { return t; }
}
```

With this we have the capability to create a `Box` holding a `String` (`Box<String> stringBox = new Box<String>();`) and a `Box` holding an `Integer` (`Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<Integer>();`). What follows is a list of some cases and their respective behaviour:

```
Box<String> stringBox   = new Box<String>();
Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<Integer>();
stringBox.set("Hello");          // ✅ compiles fine
integerBox.set(new Integer(10)); // ✅ compiles fine
stringBox.set(new Integer(10));  // ❌ compile-time error: incompatible types String and Integer
integerBox.set("Hello");         // ❌ compile-time error: incompatible types Integer and String
String  s  = stringBox.get();    // ✅ compiles fine
Integer i  = integerBox.get();   // ✅ compiles fine
Integer i2 = stringBox.get();    // ❌ compile-time error: incompatible types String and Integer
String  s2 = integerBox.get();   // ❌ compile-time error: incompatible types Integer and String
```

We moved the problem detection from runtime to compile-time, honing the [fail-fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) design. Nice, isn't it?

Comment: First it says you can pass anything into the set method as long as it's not a primitive type, which is obviously true, so I can pass a reference of type String to the method, and the method will set that field value to a String, resulting in no run time error. That's what I don't get, it seems like first they are saying I can pass anything, and then they're are saying I can't

Comment: You can can pass anything IN, the problem is the cast after getting something OUT.

Answer (score 0):

**These are the cases the paragraph is talking about:**

This one compiles, and runs successfully.

```java
Box b = new Box();
b.set(42.0);
double root = Math.sqrt((Double)b.get());
System.out.println(root);
```

This one compiles, but has a runtime error.

```java
Box b = new Box();
b.set("hello");
double root = Math.sqrt((Double)b.get());
System.out.println(root);
```

*The true answer to your question in the title: "Place" is just being used for the box metaphor that the tutorial is trying to use. They are just talking about calling the `set` method.*

Answer (score -1):

I honestly think it is just referring to the class, not an imaginary 'box'. Generics allow you to restrict what data can be used in this specific instance of the class. Using `Objects` instead of `Generics` will not have the same restriction - as all classes in Java are sub-classes of `Object` you will be able to pass any data type to it which may result in runtime error when Java will be trying to do some manipulations/call methods on those objects.

Comment: I sort of disagree. I think the tutorial is confusing and is trying to use an imaginary box as a metaphor for the class, but uses a word like "place" for the metaphorical box, not for the class itself.

Comment: Since the type "Box" is not parameterized it can take any Object, which may lead to run-time errors in a class that frequently uses the Box class?

Comment: In short, yes. The problem arises if you create an array of `Box` type for example:
`ArrayList<Box> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Integer(1)); list.add("Animal");`
if you try to call `.length()` method on every element - you will get runtime error when trying to call it on [0] but not on [1]